# How to use HTML tags at Laravel lang?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple translation:

```
'craft_summ' => ' &nbsp; coin|coins ',
```

but at site i received **only** coins.

I use at my controller files localization. My trans function looks like:

```
'message' =>. $summa. trans_choice('notify.craft_summ', $summa).,
```

I need that `trans_choice` understood HTML tags, how can I do this?

Because here i can't use `{!! !!}` because it's not blade file

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

Displaying Unescaped Data
By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

Hello, {!! $name !!}.

---

Try to use `htmlspecialchars_decode` function

Comment: thank you for reply! i try to use `htmlspecialchars_decode(trans_choice('notify.craft_summ', $summa))`
and now i received only word coins, without `&nbsp`  and without space

Comment: but i can't use space. now in my code i use `htmlspecialchars_decode(trans_choice('notify.craft_summ', $summa))`, at lang file i use `'craft_summ' => ' &nbsp; coin|coins ',` but at site it show: `51coins` without space

Comment: maybe you should hardcode this:
'message' => $summa . ' ' . trans_choice('notify.craft_summ', $summa),